# json-server add read-only route with middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, json-server

In my json-server setup I'd like to set a read-only route.

So instead of setting that route in the `db.json` file, I'm using a middleware (named `middleware.js`):

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.url === '/authenticate') {
    res.body = {
      some_property: "some_value"
    };
    console.log("triggered!!!");
  }
  next();
};
```

so I run it giving:

> json-server --watch db.json --middlewares middleware.js

the problem is that, despite the `if` block is triggered and I can see the `console.log` message, the body of the response will always be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue using:

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.url === '/authenticate') {
    res.send({
      some_property: "some_value"
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```